# Get order customer details

Tags: orders, customer, export

I would like to get customer details from all orders, specifically email address and company name if it exists. When I export customers via the Magento export menu, I only get a limited list of registered customers. We have many customers who don't register, and I want to have them in the list as well.

It's OK to do this via MySQL. Export to CSV is even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the `sales_flat_order_address` table on `parent_id` with the `sales_flat_order` table, and filter out the desired address (billing or shipping) by filtering on `address_type` in the address table.

Or you can go search the web for a decent order export module, which has options to export addresses and the possibility to export to CSV.